# How does the distance of a function from cantor set look like?

Tags: graphing-functions, cantor-set

While reading [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Distance_from_Point_to_Subset_is_Continuous_Function#:%7E:text=Let%20f%3AX%E2%86%92R,Then%20f%20is%20continuous.) result (which claims continuity but actually proves uniform continuity), I wondered how do such functions (on $\mathbb R$) look like?

For a singleton set $\{a\}$, it would be $|x-a|$.

This is easily extended to all finite sets: for a finite set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ (where $a_i<a_{i+1}\:\forall\:i$). The function will be
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
|x-a_1|&\text{ if }x\le\frac{a_1+a_2}2\\
|x-a_2|&\text{ if }\frac{a_1+a_2}2<x\le\frac{a_2+a_3}2\\
\ \,\quad\vdots&\\
|x-a_{n-1}|&\text{ if }\frac{a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}}{2}<x\le\frac{a_{n-1}+a_n}{2}\\
|x-a_n|&\text{ if }x>\frac{a_{n-1}+a_n}2
\end{cases}$$
So the graph of this function would be like $|x|$ at the ends, with lots of zig-zag lines in the middle (unlike a single sharp point like that in $|x|$).

Countable sets may go similarly, like for integers we get infinitely many zig-zag lines.

But it may also be different for some countable sets, like it is constant $0$ function for rationals.

For bounded intervals, we get the absolute value functions towards the end and constant $0$ function in the middle. For unbounded intervals, it is absolute value function on one side and $0$ on the other (except for $(-\infty,\infty)$, for which it is constant $0$ throughout).

Union of intervals can be managed similarly, and I suppose all open sets will work similarly, because they are countable union of disjoint open intervals.

And then, I thought of Cantor set and got stuck. It is easy to see that the function is $|x|$ before zero and $|x-1|$ after $1$, but what happens inside the unit interval, that I could not see (since the cantor set is also not dense like the set of rationals, the distance is $\frac16$ for $\frac12$).

Comment: Since the cantor set is compact and a singleton point $x$ is closed, it follows that if $x \not \in C$, then $d(x,C) > 0$. Not to say that this answers your question, but at least you know it’s not going to behave like $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Joe We don't need compactness for that. For any set $A$ if $d(x,A)=0$ but $x\notin A$, it means $x\in A'$ (the set of all limit points of $A$), so closedness is enough. 
But this is not what I am interested in, I want to see an explicit expression of distance, if possible, otherwise some insights on its graph.

Comment: Ah yes, that  works because the singleton $x$ itself is compact! In general though, for closed sets $A$ and $B$, even when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint it need not be the case that $d(A,B) > 0$.

Comment: There is a small picture of the graph of this function for the Cantor set on page 15 of T. W. Gamelin & R. E. Greene, *Introduction to Topology* (2nd ed. Dover 1999).

Comment: You can get an idea of what it looks like by looking at $d(x,C_n)$ for a few iterations of approximating the Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ denote the Cantor set. It will suffice to understand how $f(x) = d(x,C)$ behaves when restricted to $[0,1] \setminus C$. Recall we may construct the Cantor set as $C = \bigcap_{n} C_n$, where $C_0 = [0,1]$, and $C_{n+1}$ is constructed from $C_n$ by removing $2^{n-1}$ open intervals. Let $I^n_1, \cdots, I^n_{2^{n-1}}$ denote the open intervals removed from $C_n$ to build $C_{n+1}$. Then we may write:
$$[0,1] \setminus C = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{m=1}^{2^{n-1}} I_m^n$$
Since the $I_m^n$ are all disjoint, it will suffice to understand the behavior of $f$ on each of these intervals. Let $a^n_m < b^n_m$ denote the left and right endpoints of $I_m^n$. For $x \in I_m^n$ it is clear that $d(x, C) = min \{ d(x, a_m^n), d(x, b_m^n) \}$. And so we have:
$$f \big \rvert_{I_m^n}(x) = \frac{b_m^n-a_m^n}{2} - \left | x - \frac{b_m^n + a_m^n}{2} \right |$$
Letting $\chi_A$ denote the characteristic function on a set $A$, we see that:
$$f \big \rvert_{[0,1]}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{2^{n-1}} \left [\frac{b_m^n-a_m^n}{2} - \left | x - \frac{b_m^n + a_m^n}{2} \right | \right ] \cdot \chi_{I_m^n}(x)$$
Since the endpoints of the removed intervals can be derived by hand, I leave the rest to you.